# How do i look at postgres data in heroku while using a shared database?

Tags: heroku

I cannot access the db directly because it is shared.  Any recommendations on how I could get pretty intricate data tables out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use the dev plan, this will allow you to ingress and runs on the same version as the production instances - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-dev-plan